# Node.js spawn/exec/execFile/win-spawn/cross-spawn all throwing Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

[image: Error]

For context, routes\index.js:87 is around my exec (sync) or inside my exec (async).

I am getting this error with either spawn, exec, or execFile, using the libraries child_process, win-spawn, or cross-spawn.

I've tried running node, npm, grunt, ant (Apache), etc. -- which all work from command line with no problems -- with and without parameters, with and without options, sync and async, and I always get this exact error (same line and column).

I spent all day yesterday looking for solutions, found solutions on here, and on Github (node), tried everything I found, but nothing solved the problem.

I will provide any info you think will help to solve the problem. Thanks for your support.

-

**Requested by Ben Fortune** (have tried sync and async of all, only shown first example):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('node', function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

-

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('node');
child.on('error', function(){ throw arguments['0']; });
```

-

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
exec('/path/to/node', function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
}
```

-

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
spawn('node', function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
}
```

-

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
spawn('cmd', ['/s', '/c', '"C:\\mycmd.bat"'], { 
    windowsVerbatimArguments: true
});
```

I have tried all of these with the packages win-spawn and cross-spawn, with and without the '.exec' (etc.) affixes to the require. I have tried options like `stdio: 'inherit'`.

I am using Windows 8.1 64-bit, running command as Administrator.

-

[Node js - Error: spawn ENOENT (Windows 8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842391/node-js-error-spawn-enoent-windows-8-1)

http://www.zescience.com/node-js-error-spawn-enoent-windows-8-1-167370

A couple of examples with the same error, except in my case, I am calling the exec function, not some 3rd party package.

I've also tried putting the exec elsewhere in code, location of the call is not the problem.

Possibly related: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2318

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: I told you I've tried exec, execFile and spawn. Do you want me to show you an example of how they are called? Do you want me to just write a huge block of code showing every combination and method I tried?

Comment: A single example will be fine.

Comment: I think it's a problem with the Node+Windows combination. I was using the same method 10 months ago and I didn't have any problems. Earlier version of Node running on Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where win-spawn and cross-spawn failed, [spawn-cmd](https://www.npmjs.org/package/spawn-cmd) worked.

I have no idea why cross-spawn didn't work when spawn-cmd did, as they're pretty similar, but there you go. As to the original problem, I guess it's an issue with node.